# shimo l2tp vpn not connecting to racoon daemon

Tags: macos

I am unable to get shimo to connect to l2tp sites as it keeps saying 'unable to launch ipsec backend racoon'

system.log is showing the below

```
May 17 21:28:48 SiMacBookPro Shimo[735]: Requesting Authentication for Modes: 2048
May 17 21:28:48 SiMacBookPro Shimo[735]: Modes after account check: 2048
May 17 21:28:48 SiMacBookPro Shimo[735]: Modes after Keychain check: 0
May 17 21:28:48 SiMacBookPro Shimo[735]: Modes after message-only check: 0
May 17 21:28:48 SiMacBookPro Shimo[735]: Modes after ignore-missing-values check: 0
May 17 21:28:48 SiMacBookPro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system): Caller not allowed to perform action: launchctl.817, action = service bootout, code = 150: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged, uid = 0, euid = 0, gid = 0, egid = 0, asid = 100000
May 17 21:28:48 SiMacBookPro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.racoon[762]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by pkill[818]
May 17 21:28:50 SiMacBookPro Shimo[735]: ERROR: Shimo was unable to launch the IPSec backend service 'racoon'. Could not start racoon daemon.
May 17 21:28:51 SiMacBookPro Shimo[735]: Reloaded racoon.conf due to changes to files in /private/var/run/Shimo/configs.
```

i can disable System Integrity Protection but i would rather not,

any ideas people?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try

> sudo killall racoon

in Terminal and then run Shimo again